# How to find RMSE of two different dimension images python? 1920 x 1080 x 3 vs 4361, 7374, 3

Tags: python, image-processing, video-processing

How to find  **RMSE** of two different dimension images python?
Example-

```
(1920 x 1080 x 3) vs (4361 x 7374 x 3)
```

if we resize it, Quality effected. what's the best solution ?